# Runtime Content Negotiation for @Consume

Tags: java, jax-rs

Imagine my resources can be addressed by `/rest/properties/<key>/data`

The supported content types depends on the property type.

For GET this is no problem: ([Runtime Content Negotiation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkqbq.html))

```
@GET 
public Response readData(@PathParam("key") String key) {
    MyProperty property = getProperty(key);
    List<Variant> variants = property.getType().getVariants();
    Variant variant = request.selectVariant(variants);
    if (null == variant) {
        return Response.notAcceptable(variants).build();
    }
    return Response.ok(property.getData(), variant).build();
    // -> registered @Provider (MessageBodyWriter) will be called
}
```

---

Now I would like to have an equivalent for 'Consumes' to use it for POST/PUT.

The common approach to define several methods is not an option because I need to calculate the type first:

So the goal is something like that:

```
@POST
public Response updateData(@PathParam("key") String key, InputStream is) {
    MyProperty property = getProperty(key);
    List<Variant> variants = property.getType().getVariants();
    Variant variant = /* get request content type */;
    if (!variants.contains(variant)) {
        return Response.status(415).build();
    }
    entity = /* delayed MessageBodyReader call?!
        readFrom(is, variant , ExpectedClass.class);
     */

    ... save entity in db or fs

    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

BTW the common approach would be:
*[would not compile (Consuming media type conflict)]*

```
@POST
@Consumes("text/plain")
public Response updateDataPlain(@PathParam("key") String key, ExpectedClass entity) {
    ... save entity in db or fs

    return Response.ok().build();
}

@POST
@Consumes("text/plain")
public Response updateDataPlain(@PathParam("key") String key, AnotherExpectedClassWhichSupportPlain entity);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should

```
@Consumes("*/*")
```

And then manually deal with the `Content-Type` HTTP header.